# how to protect ideas in question?

Tags: discussion, idea

Is there any way to protect you ideas when you asking question ?
Assuming you ask a problem that provides new ideas innovative, Which ensures that these ideas will be your property and not be stolen by other users ? Is it possible to protect these ideas by the community making them the property of the user and linked to his account.

Comment: No. -----------

Comment: Hire a consultant.  Have him sign an NDA (non-disclosure agreement).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no legal protection provided by posting your idea on the internet, other than the proof that you already had the idea at the time of writing.

Moreover, anything that you write here is "licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)", as the footer says.

Comment: So, if you have a new idea in your problem, and you want to share it with other users to have profetional advice, the forum will not be the best place ?

Comment: @codo if you don't want to disclose your idea, or if you don't want anyone to copy it, it's not helpful to put it on the Internet in any case. First protect yourself and then reach out.

Answer (score 10):

It's best to assume that anything you post here is a gift which you're offering to anyone in the world to use in any way they deem fit.

Answer (score 8):

Electronics is all about stealing other peoples circuit (ideas) and then bending them to your application.  If you don't want to share, steal and be stolen from, then don't post.

Comment: Is not only about circuit, some times is about new concept and I do not specifically talk about my case

Comment: @codo: Anything you post here becomes *publicly disclosed*. If you don't like that, don't post here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Again! I don't have anything to post here, is not a personal question.